# I would like to change Rails default redirect code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm modifying an existing project, and I want my app to have only status: 301 redirects instead of Rails default 302. As there is a lot of places in the app where redirect_to is used, I would like to skip modifying all of them and adding status: 301 as a parameter, so I would like if possible to change default rails redirect code for my app to be 301, or if that's not possible then somehow "hijack" 302 redirect and change it to 301.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monkeypatch the redirect_to method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def redirect_to_with_permanence(options = {}, response_status = {})
    response_status.reverse_merge! status: :moved_permanently 
    redirect_to_without_permanence options, response_status
  end
  alias_method_chain :redirect_to, :permanence
end
```

Comment: tnx, that's exactly what i wanted to do

Comment: Why is the rails default 302 and not 302? As I understood, 301 is more recommended in most cases

Comment: 302 is the safer default option. A 301 might be cached by the client and thus break a redirection when it changes. In fact, the recommendation is that clients replace the original URL with the redirection and not call the original URL on subsequent requests. For example a bookmarking service might save the URL redirected to instead of the one entered. From RFC 2616: “The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs”. If someone doesn't know the details they might not anticipate this possible side effect.